# Angular one request for three parts on the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have nav-bar, home-content, and footer. in all of them i need to display the same data, but they are in different controllers.
I try to do one request in run phase and insert the data to a service and share this data. but the problem is the delay because of the promise pattern.
Im trying to avoid from put this in the rootScope.
Some one have better idea?

example in run phase:

```
    PostsService.getPosts().then(function(data) {
      PostsService.posts = res.data;
    }

the controllers:

//home
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
         url: "/",
         controller:HomeController,
         templateUrl: "views/home/index.html"
    });

// nav controller

    $scope.posts= PostsService.posts;

    console.log(PostsService.posts) // is an empty array

the html:

//home view

//return data

    <div ng-repeat="posts in posts">
      <p>{{post.body}}</p>
    </div>

//nav view is not return data

    <section ng-controller="NavController">
    <div ng-repeat="posts in posts">
      <p>{{post.body}}</p>
    </div>
    </section>

//footer
    <section ng-controller="FooterController">
    <div ng-repeat="posts in posts">
      <p>{{post.body}}</p>
    </div>
    </section>
```

plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/CmpkURaG3ynIBVxwSpAM?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having finally debugged your plunker, the problem seems to lie in the object reference.

You are using

```
UsersService.users = data.res
```

So the reference of users before call and after call changes.
MainCtrl is being loaded before the data is fetched (load orders confirmed using console statements)
NavCtrl is being loaded after.

So MainCtrl is still bound to the older users object reference which is [] and continues to be bound to this object even after data is fetched, because this method creates a new users object instead of updating the old one.

One easy solution will be to keep the reference same like:

```
app.run(function($http, usersService) {

  $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(function(res) {

    usersService.users.length = 0 ;// empties the user object
    //copy the array
    Array.prototype.push.apply(usersService.users, res.data);
  });
});
```

Comment: But why this is happen, services are singleton, the reference not should be the same?

Comment: The service is singleton. But the users object inside is not a constant and so its reference can vary.  When you initialize data, you assign it an empty array, which is memory location 1. And when you fetch data and get json, this data is a different memory location.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `ui-router`, you may put your loading logic into a state's `resolve` (instead of a generic `run` function) to wait with state resolution until the loading is completed. Then you can inject the resolved local service into state's controller (you can even do it in sub-states).

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
    // ...
    resolve: {
        posts: ['PostsService', function (PostsService) {
            return PostsService.getPosts();
        }]
    },
    controller: ['$scope', 'posts', function ($scope, posts) {
        $scope.posts = posts;
    }]
});
```

[See documentation.](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve)

Comment: I like this approach except I'd say avoid using rootScope. If PostService could locally cache the posts to avoid further requests, then each controller could just hit up PostService for the posts as needed.

Comment: You're right, using `$rootScope` here is nasty. It was just the shortest way to demostrate the point. I'll improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate on *"delay because of promise pattern"* ?
There should be no difference in working of this code the way you're using Service or $rootScope.

Comment: When i do this in the run phase its loading the view before resolving the promise

Comment: It would help to see your code and how you're doing it. Could you post it or probably a plunker ?

Comment: I wrote in the question, this is the code in the run phase, what you want me to add?

Comment: Angular's view load is not delayed just because promise is being used. I was assuming that you have put the promise resolution on your routes. This is how you delay controller load and hence the view load until you get your data from the APIs. You need to put a resolve block for your routes. Have you done this ?

Comment: The console.log logging empty array can have two reasons
1. The data you got back from server is actually empty (might be worthwhile to debug it).
2. Your promise has not been resolved when you reach this console block.

For second case, you might need to watch the PostServices.posts and then use it when you have data in it (until you use it in view alone). What Fenex wrote should work.

Comment: No in the home controller its not empty

Comment: Sorry I hit enter before it was time. Update my comment.

Comment: I try to this $scope.$watch('PostsService.posts', function(posts) {
  console.log(posts) // not change
})

Comment: Could you setup a fiddle/plunker so that we can nail this. We could do more than just guesswork then. Its very easy to set it up. Let know if you need help for that.

Comment: Ok i will try setup plunker

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65455/discussion-between-mkhanal-and-angularavel).

Answer (score 0):

Services are singletons. In all parts (controllers, factories, etc) of the modules, our variable `ServicePost` points to the same object. So, if you change variable `posts` in "run" block, in controllers value will change too.
Why not it?

JS:

```
angular.module('app', ['app.posts-service' /*our service  there*/])
.run(function(PostsService) {
    PostsService().getPosts().then(function(data) {
        PostsService.posts = res.data;
    })
})
.controller('One', function($scope, PostsService) {
    $scope.PostsService = PostService;
})
.controller('Two', function($scope, PostsService) {
   $scope.PostsService = PostService;
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng:controller="One">
    <ul>
        <my:post ng:repeat="post in PostsService.posts" />
    </ul>
</div>
<div ng:controller="Two">
    <ul>
        <my:post ng:repeat="post in PostsService.posts" />
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: while that may solve the problem an explanation would help the op and other users understand that you did there.

Comment: I try your answer and update my question because its not working